# How to set limit on a Collection in Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to query for some data that is of type Collection (according to Eloquent). When I query I want to set an upper bound. However, I cannot enforce this using

```
$data->skip(0)->take(5)->get();
```

nor by using

```
$data->offset(0)->limit(5)->get();
```

because `$data` is already a Collection and no longer a Builder type. How can I get the same functionality for Collection type?

Comment: Have you tried using `$data->skip(0)->take(5)` (without the `->get()`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get use the [`slice()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-slice) method to get a subset of the Collection.

```
$data->slice(0, 5);
```